# jQuery How to find the numeric value From content

Tags: ajax, jquery

how can i filter my content to get numeric value from content.? for example here is my html code. there is one **div style-div**   it contains some content. there is some numeric value in content. how can i filter content to get numeric value only.?

what i am doing is first get thE numeric value from the content and then display the number of chair images below the text.

is there any code to filter content and get the numeric value from the content?

```
 <div class="style-div">there are 24 chairs</div>
```

Comment: Is there always exactly one numeric value in the content? It won't ever be something like "There are 24 type-2 chairs"? Will it always be an integer?

Comment: there will be multiple div that contain similar type of content with different numeric . any guide to make it more simple USING ARRAY FOR MULTIPLE divs.

Comment: Your question explicitly states "there is _one_ div" (my emphasis). Now you say there are multiple. And you didn't actually answer the questions in my previous comment, i.e., can the individual content of one of the divs contain more than one numeric value? Please click "edit" and add all of the details to your question rather than drip-feeding it to us via comments.

Comment: Isn't this kind of question already been answered thousand times before?...

Comment: i am just asking you the possibilities. what if there will be more div  that's it. about answer to your question there won't be any other integer value. there will be only 1 integer value and some text. like 34 chairs or 9 chairs or 4 tables.

Comment: `var arrValues =  $('.style-div').text().match(/\d+/g);` will return integer value but as string. Could be just enough for what you are looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the text and use a regular expression to extract the (first) numeric value in it:

```
var text = $("div.style-div").text();
var match = text.match(/\d+/);
var num = match && parseInt(match[0], 10);
```

`num` will be a number for the **first** matching series of digits in the text, or `null` if there was no match. Subsequent numbers (e.g., "There are 24 type-2 chairs" as nnnnnn mentioned) will be ignored.

It can be a one-liner (if you like that kind of thing; I find them hard to debug) if you're **sure** the number will be there:

```
var num = parseInt($("div.style-div").text().match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
```

...but if there's no number, that will throw an error because we end up trying to do `null[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex

```
$('.style-div').text().match(/\d+/);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YGBqp/)**

Comment: will work assuming only one number in the string and for the first occurrence of the div with that class name

Comment: there will be multiple div that contain similar type of content with different numeric . any guide to make it more simple USING ARRAY FOR MULTIPLE divs

Answer (score 0):

My possible solution.

1.Get the `value`.

2.Split with space.

3.Loop it and use  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/ .

4.Push numeric values in to array

ex:

```
$.isNumeric("-10");  // true
```